# Slick Carousel with multiple instances became crazy with infinite width (among other things)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, webflow

I'm facing some "bugs" with the Slick carousel.
My problem is that I've multiple instances of the Slick slider, I've searched for some information about how to make it and I'm trying it but I have no results...

It creates a crazy width for the slider (like 1.93229e+06px of width) or in other cases, it makes a 0px width of the slides or makes the slides with a 354048px of width (for example).

I'm using Webflow and its CMS. I don't know if that's the problem.
I attach some screenshots and my JS code for the Slick Carousel.
If you need more info please, tell me.

```
<script>
// when document is fully loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.game-screenshots-list').each(function (i, item) {
      var sliderID = "screenshotSlider" + i;
      this.id = sliderID;
      
      $(this).slick({
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '9px',
          speed: 700,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: true,
          touchThreshold: 300,
          mobileFirst: true,
          dots: false,
          appendArrows: '#' + sliderID + '.game-screenshot-nav',
          prevArrow: '#' + sliderID + '.game-screenshot-nav .prev-arrow',
          nextArrow: '#' + sliderID + '.game-screenshot-nav .next-arrow',
      });
  });
});

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
    var screenShotSliders = $(".game-screenshots-list");
  
  screenShotSliders.each(function() {
    $(this).slick('resize');
        $(this).slick('refresh');
  });
});

</script>
```

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzYF9.jpg)

[Webflow structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeGp7.png)

[Webflow structure values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYNNW.png)

I've used another Slick Carousel on another page with CMS too and it works perfectly, I don't know if the problem is that in the other Slick Slider is an Images Collection of a CMS item Collection...

[Cool Slick Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7h5.jpg)

Any suggestions? I would be appreciated your help!

Regards

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Maybe try a vanilla instance of Slick carousel to get a better feel of how it should work, and possibly pinpoint whether the problem is with your implementation of the slider or a problem interfacing with webflow. Good tutorials at https://www.divinectorweb.com/2020/11/how-to-use-slick-slider-for-your-website.html or https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick.html

Comment: Hi Hektor! thanks for your answer. I'm facing this bug by using multiple instances of the Slick Carousel plugin. I'm using another one on another page of the website and works perfectly...